# Android fragment classnotfoundexception

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am following following link to create fragment in anadroid

http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments

but it always gives classnotfound exception.Please guide me on how to resolve it ?

Logcat :

```
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment/com.example.fragment.FragmentProjectActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.example.fragment.FragmentProjectActivity.onCreate(FragmentProjectActivity.java:11)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  ... 11 more
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.fragment-2.apk]
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
07-25 14:45:22.511: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  ... 20 more
```

Comment: have you added support library?

Comment: This should help you. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks everybody for your valuable response.. my pakage name was not correct..i corrected it and resolved it..:)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an API lvl higher than Lvl 11?
The Fragment was added since Lvl 11.

The StackTrace shows that it tries loading the class 'android.view.fragment'
But the Fragment class is located at 'android.app.Fragment', so something is really wrong.

Something might be wrong with you .xml layout files.
Or the SDK version you are developping on is an old one.

For better analysis pls post some more code (.xml files and .java files)

See the docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html